# Sikulix administrator right issue

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I need to add to my selenium script a sikulix script to do a task that selenium can't do. When I run bellow script

```
C:\Sikulix\\runsikulix.cmd -r C:\Sikulix\Scritps\WorkFlow.sikuli
```

from normal or elevated CMD it works fine. But when I run it from normal or elevated pycharm

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen,STDOUT
from pprint import pprint as pp


command = "C:\Sikulix\\runsikulix.cmd -r C:\Sikulix\Scritps\WorkFlow.sikuli"
process = Popen(command,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
end = process.communicate()
pp(end)
```

it does not work and I got bellow error.

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
(b'+++ JAVA_HOME specified but not useable C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_1'
 b'52\\bin\r\n+++ looking for Java in system path and then in standard places\r'
 b'\n+++ running this Java\r\n+++ trying to run SikuliX\r\n+++ using: -Xms64'
 b'M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine -jar C:\\Sikuli'
 b'x\\sikulix.jar -r C:\\Sikulix\\Scritps\\WorkFlow.sikuli\r\n[error] RobotDe'
 b'sktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(960,540)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]\nbut '
 b'after move is L(768,432)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]\nPossible cause in case you '
 b'did not touch the mouse while script was running:\n Mouse actions are blo'
 b'cked generally or by the frontmost application.\nYou might try to run the'
 b' SikuliX stuff as admin.\r\n[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: shou'
 b'ld be L(3600,675)@S(1)[2400,0 2400x1350]\nbut after move is L(5385,920)@S'
 b'(2)[4800,0 2400x1350]\nPossible cause in case you did not touch the mouse'
 b' while script was running:\n Mouse actions are blocked generally or by th'
 b'e frontmost application.\nYou might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin'
 b'.\r\n[error] script [ C:\\Sikulix\\Scritps\\WorkFlow.sikuli ] stopped wit'
 b'h error at line --unknown--\r\n[error] Error caused by: Traceback (most re'
 b'cent call last):\n  File "C:\\Sikulix\\Scritps\\WorkFlow.sikuli\\WorkFlow'
 b'.py", line 1, in <module>\n    doubleClick("WybierzPlik-1.PNG")\n  Line 27'
 b'61, in file Region.java\n\r\n\tat org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:'
 b'2761)\r\n\tat org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2326)\r\n\tat org.'
 b'sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3220)\r\n\tat org.si'
 b'kuli.script.Region.doubleClick(Region.java:3767)\r\n\tat org.sikuli.script.'
 b'Region.doubleClick(Region.java:3752)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccess'
 b'orImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.'
 b'invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.inv'
 b'oke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)'
 b'\r\norg.sikuli.script.FindFailed: FindFailed: WybierzPlik-1.PNG: (75x19) i'
 b'n S(0)[0,0 1920x1080] E:Y, T:3.0\n  Line 2761, in file Region.java\n\n\r\n',
 None)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried in other IDE.

Inside "C:\Sikulix\Scritps\WorkFlow.sikuli" is simple hover

I am on Python 3.7
SikuliX-1.1.3
Windows 10 x64 
User Administrator,
User Account Control Settings set to max.

**EDIT**

I tested os.system() command and the mouse moved a bit, but stopped and on console was blocked error message as above with a bit more information.

```
[error] script [ C:\Sikulix\Scritps\WorkFlow.sikuli ] stopped with error at 

line --unknown--
[error] Error caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Sikulix\Scritps\WorkFlow.sikuli\WorkFlow.py", line 1, in <module>
    doubleClick("WybierzPlik-1.PNG")
  Line 2761, in file Region.java

    at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2761)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2326)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3220)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.doubleClick(Region.java:3767)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.doubleClick(Region.java:3752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.sikuli.script.FindFailed: FindFailed: WybierzPlik-1.PNG: (75x19) in S(0)[0,0 1920x1080] E:Y, T:3.0
  Line 2761, in file Region.java
```

**Solution**

Ok, I have found working not elegant solution.
I changed access control here to full for all users(I am too lazy to check which one needed it)

[image]